# In date_select, 2 is added to "day" when 0 is put in "year"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.2.2.1
I think you don't understand what I say, I put the log and explain it.

## Log

```
[INFO]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  : Started PATCH "/users/43" for ::1 at 2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900
[INFO]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  : Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
[INFO]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5cFNucU6SLuSUeiSvu4QCRy7MvQ8BycoFF8wvfnbQ4tebelTt6U22hEFKiSAe7poNtdpBOY3k8SmtyUXez4lGA==", "user"=>{"user_image_attributes"=>{"id"=>"57"}, "name"=>"test", "user_info_attributes"=>{"sex"=>"", "birth_day(2i)"=>"1", "birth_day(3i)"=>"11", "birth_day(1i)"=>"0", "id"=>"3", "introduction"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"43"}
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 43 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ /Users/hasegawawataru/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 43 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   UserImage Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `user_images`.* FROM `user_images` WHERE `user_images`.`user_id` = 43 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   UserInfo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `user_infos`.* FROM `user_infos` WHERE `user_infos`.`user_id` = 43 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 43 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/models/application_record.rb:56
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 43 LIMIT 1  [["id", 43], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/models/application_record.rb:56
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   UserInfo Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE `user_infos` SET `sex` = '', `birth_day` = '0000-01-13', `updated_at` = '2019-04-03 08:36:37' WHERE `user_infos`.`id` = 3
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
```

## Detail

```
Line 3<br>
"user_info_attributes"=>{"sex"=>"", "birth_day(2i)"=>"1", "birth_day(3i)"=>"11", "birth_day(1i)"=>"0", "id"=>"3", "introduction"=>""}
```

1i = year
2i = month
3i = day
The log means birth_day parameter is 0000-01-11(year-month-day).

```
Line 18<br>
[DEBUG]2019-04-03 17:36:37 +0900:  :   UserInfo Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE `user_infos` SET `sex` = '', `birth_day` = '0000-01-13', `updated_at` = '2019-04-03 08:36:37' WHERE `user_infos`.`id` = 3
```

However, "day" plus 2 is registered in the database.
If 1i (year) is not 0 but 1990 etc., it will be registered successfully without being plus 2.

## Discovery history

I discovered in the test when I updated from Rails 5.2.2 to 5.2.2.1, but I don't know whether that is the cause.
However, when the date_select function was introduced, it worked without any problems.

Any idea about this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a DB issue more than a Rails one since the update query is well formed. Maybe your DB can't handle year 0 properly.

Test `UPDATE user_infos SET sex = '', birth_day = '0000-01-13', updated_at = '2019-04-03 08:36:37' WHERE user_infos.id = 3` in your DB client.

Comment: I do not know the reason at all, but it seems that 0 was bad as you expected.
When I set 1900 not 0, it worked without being a plus 2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bear in mind that dates are stored as timestamps, meaning the distance in seconds since [1970/01/01](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), so year zero is causing an overflow.